# Using PHP variables when echoing data from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `index.php` page that includes `settings.php`

in the `settings.php` file, I have some PHP Variables with data, like phone numbers, names etc.

on my `index.php` file i am selecting data from a MySQL table and echoing it on the screen, i want to be able to have the variables from the `settings.php` file in the database so they will echo on the `index.php` page

how is this possible?

Comment: Surely you would first just need to insert that data into your database first. You can do that in your PHP if you want it to run every time. Or even just simply using the prompt to perform an insert query.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**settings.php**

```
<?php
$valueFromSettings="Settings.php";
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include("settings.php");
echo $valueFromSettings; //Prints Settings.php
```

Alternatively, you can make use of **`include_once()`**, **`require()`**, **`require_once()`** .. all of these are language constructs.. but beware of **`require()`** and **`require_once()`** as they spit **`FATAL`** errors if your PHP file to be included does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

settings.php

```
 <?php
  $phone='12345';
  //declare all of your variables here
 ?>
```

and in index.php get these variables as

```
<?php
 include(settings.php);
 $query='SELECT phone FROM table where phone="'.$phone.'"';

?>
```

Hope it will help you